# htaccess rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to change the link "www.foo.com/files/bar.jpg" to "www.foo.com/bar.jpg".

Ive tried the following code in my .htaccess, without success:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . /files [L]
```

Did i miss something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^files/(.*) /$1 [L]
```

**EDIT**

From your comments below if you wanted your url to files.foo.com then your directory structure should be:

```
files
  - .htaccess
  - files
    - bar.jpg
public_html (or www)
```

Comment: Hmm, it still doesnt work. Could it be because the url looks like "files.foo.com/files/img.jpg" at the moment?

Comment: What URL are you typing in? With that rule all you would need to enter would be www.file.com/bar.jpg

Comment: files.foo.com/img.jpg for example. Do i need to change the htaccess for that?

Comment: Just make sure your paths are ok. From what you are saying you should now have a subdirectory called files with a files directory in it, a htaccess file with the above rules. The files directory should have the image in. If any of those reside in the main www or public_html directory then we need to rethink.

Comment: "From what you are saying you should now have a subdirectory called files with a files directory in it". Dont you mean a subdir called files with images in it? the .htaccess is located in the public_html root, and the images are located in the "files" subfolder.

Comment: Edited answer for clarification

Answer (score 0):

if you make SEO link for your website probably you would face the problem that your images do not show on the  page because actually the address of them does not make sens from current SEO address in this condition you can put this code in your .

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?(css|images)/(.*) $2/$3 [L]
```

For more information check this link 
http://www.yasha.co/htaccess/url-rewrite-example-tips-and-tricks/article-3.html